# Extract substring in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

If I have a string e.g. "XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZZ" and I want to extract YYYY (so between the two "-" as number of carachters may differ). How can this be done?

Br

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have codes to share so we can see where is your problem? And what programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use RegEx for this but this method uses simple string functions.

```
=MID(Fields!str.Value, 
Instr(Fields!str.Value, "-")+1,
Instr(Instr(Fields!str.Value, "-")+1, Fields!str.Value, "-") - Instr(Fields!str.Value, "-") - 1
)
```

replace `Fields!str.Value` with the correct field name from your dataset

Here's the result based on some sample data

[image]